# Options for migration Microsoft Access forms

Tags: ms-access, migration

I am having a look at options from migrating MS Access 2007 databases to another web-based platform, that's including both the UI (forms) as well as the back-end.

One of my primary concerns is the time to port the UI forms/business logic. I'd like to get suggestions on which tools (such as Oracle APEX Application Migration Workshop) have the capability to automate that to some degree.

Comment: I've never used it myself, but I think the new MSFT platform for basic crud-like apps is that new Lightswitch, or Lighthouse, or whatever the heck it's called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify what hosting platform you have or are contemplating (if any), there are several options, both hosted and host-it-yourself, including:

Hosted services: [Zoho Creator](http://www.zoho.com/creator/migrate-msaccess-database.html) and [Springbase](http://www.springbase.com/access-database-conversion) that require that the provider hosts your converted database/application,

and

Converters that will create the hostable code and database for you to host yourself: [Wavemaker](https://www.wavemaker.com/), [DBConvert](http://dbconvert.com/products.php?pDB=1#access)

Comment: I'm primarily looking at in-house solutions - thanks for those suggestions, but can't see any Zoho Creator or Wavemaker options to migrate existing Access forms, which is what I'm after.